# Making GET request to a tiktok url in order to get a canonical link

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to make a GET request to a tiktok url via python but it does not work.

Let's say we have a tiktok link from a mobile app – https://vt.tiktok.com/ZS81uRSRR/ and I want to get its **video_id** which is available in a canonical link. This is the canonical link for the provided tiktok: https://www.tiktok.com/@notorious_foodie/video/7169643841316834566?_r=1&_t=8XdwIuoJjkX&is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7169643841316834566

**video_id** comes after `/video/`, for example in the link above video_id would be **7169643841316834566**

When I open a mobile link on my laptop in a browser it redirects me to the canonical link, I wanted to achieve the same behavior via code and managed to do it like so:

```
import requests
def get_canonical_url(url):
    return requests.get(url, timeout=5).url
```

It was working for a while but then it started raising timeout errors every time, I managed to fix it by providing cookie. I made a request to Postman(it works when I make GET request through postman though), copied cookies, modified my function to accept cookies and it started working again. It had been working with cookies for ~6  months although last week it stopped working again, I thought that the reason might be in the expired cookies but when I updated them it didn't help.

This is the error I keep getting:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.tiktok.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

The weirdest thing is that I can make my desired request just fine via `curl`:
[image]

Or via Postman:

[image]

---

**Recap**

So the problem is that my python GET request never succeeded and I can't understand why. I tried using VPN in case tiktok has banned my ip, also I tried to run this request on some of my servers to try different server locations but none of my attempts worked.

Could you give me a piece of advice how to debug this issue further or maybe any other ideas how I can get video_id out of mobile tiktok link?

Comment: This maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62635027/13454049

Comment: @Nineteendo I tried to apply the headers from the link but it still gives the same timeout error : (

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't test it in Python 3. Luckily you found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1 - Using subprocess**

Execute curl command and catch the output and it will take ~0.5 seconds.

```
import subprocess
import re
process_detail = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "https://vt.tiktok.com/ZS81uRSRR/"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process_detail.communicate()[0].decode()
process_detail.kill()
canonical_link = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)+\?", output).group("url")
print("Canonical link: ", canonical_link)
```

**Method 2 - Using proxies**

We need to use [proxies](https://free-proxy-list.net/). here is the solution for free proxies which we can scrap and apply dynamically using BeautifulSoup..

First install BeautifulSoup using `pip install BeautifulSoup`

**Solution**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def scrap_now(url):
    print(f"<======================> Scrapping Started <======================>")
    print(f"<======================> Getting proxy <======================>")
    source = requests.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
    ips_container = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "table table-striped table-bordered"})
    ip_trs = ips_container[0].findAll('tr')
    for i in ip_trs[1:]:
        proxy_ip = i.findAll('td')[0].text + ":" + i.findAll('td')[1].text
        try:
            proxy = {"https": proxy_ip}
            print(f"<======================> Trying with: {proxy_ip}<======================>")
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
            resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=5)
            if resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                print(f"<======================> Got Success with: {proxy_ip}<======================>")
                return resp.url
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
    return ""


canonical_link = scrap_now("https://vt.tiktok.com/ZS81uRSRR/")
print("Canonical link: ", canonical_link)
```

Output:
[image]

**Method - 3: Using Selenium**

We can do this with selenium as well. It will take almost 5 seconds
First, install selenium using `pip install selenium==3.141.0`

then execute below lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1,
    "credentials_enable_service": False,
    "profile.password_manager_enabled": False
})
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(cache_valid_range=365).install(), options=options)
browser.get("https://vt.tiktok.com/ZS81uRSRR/")
print("Canonical link: ", browser.current_url)
```

**Note:** On first run it will take a bit more time as it will download web drivers automatically, but after that it will use cache only.

Comment: That's the resulting link, a redirect is asked.

Comment: Yeah, can be achievable with the same code, I've updated the response @Nineteendo

Comment: @UsmanArshad your solution works for me although it takes ~20 seconds to get a canonical link which is x10 times slower than I need. So far I'm using a workaround with running `curl` from python and it works within ~1-2sec every time.

Do you know by any chance, why your solution works in python with proxies but `curl` in terminal works fine without any proxies? Ideally I would like to avoid using proxies and just send get requests right away since it's achievable either with curl or postman.

I'm going to wait for other answers and accept your if nobody will provide a better one.

Comment: Actually  if we go without proxies in request server can identify it is an automated request. It depends on service provider they want to allow automation or not.

Can you tell me, where you want to execute the script like on: local machine or on server? if you want to execute it locally I can try to provide one more solution with `selenium` @qwertyqwerty

Comment: @qwertyqwerty -  I've updated the answer with selenium as well. It will decrease the time to ~5 seconds.

Comment: @qwertyqwerty - I've added 3 Methods, Method 1 - (Using subprocess) can be the solution you are looking for!

Comment: @UsmanArshad thanks, selenium solution works better indeed. Answering your question, I'm going to run this script on a server.

Thanks for your efforts either way : )

Comment: @UsmanArshad yeah, the curl solution is my current workaround although it looks hacky to be honest so I'm not proud of it